# Typing "k" closes search

Tags: search

Typing "k" closes the Ubuntu/Unity search box. This means I can't search for anything containing a "k". I can't seem to find any relevant keyboard shortcut that I could've messed up or anyone else who's experienced this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the shortcut "Super+K" for action "Close window" seems to have fixed the issue.

Still doesn't make any sense, though.